# What does the chinese lettering mean on my shirt?

Tags: meaning, word, character-identification

[image]

I bought this shirt and now I'm curious what the Chinese lettering means. i tried to translate, but it is very hard. Can you help me translate?

Comment: How did you try to translate it? Why didn't it work?

Comment: 情绪稳定 ..........

Comment: @fefe is right. It means emotionally stable - I don't understand why it's on your shirt.

Comment: @T-Pioneer. Quote：- “ I don't understand why it's on your shirt“ It is meant to tell people that it is safe to come near the wearer? A more colloquial one is “我不咬人”  -- I don't bite.

Comment: You should get another T-shirt saying “毫无波澜”, which means the same but in a more amusing way.

Answer (score 2):

That means Emotionally Stable.

It is in Traditional Chinese - 情緒穩定.

If you want it in Simplified Chinese, it's 情绪稳定.
If you want it in Pinyin(Pronunciation), it's:

qíng xù  wěn dìng
情   绪   稳   定

[Google Translate Link](https://www.google.com/search?ei=1QNCX73-Fseb9QOfwr3YBw&q=%E6%83%85%E7%BB%AA%E7%A8%B3%E5%AE%9A%20English&oq=%E6%83%85%E7%BB%AA%E7%A8%B3%E5%AE%9A%20English&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQzQI6BAgAEEc6BAgAEAw6AggAOgQIABBDOgYIABAEEB46CAgAEAUQBBAeOgYIIRAKECpQnRRY0ClgqitoAnABeACAAdMCiAHWEZIBBzAuNS40LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj9vPr30LDrAhXHTX0KHR9hD3sQ4dUDCAw&uact=5&safe=active&ssui=on)

Comment: Uh... You mean it is in Traditional Chinese or Simplified Chinese?

Comment: It is in Traditional Chinese, sorry if I made it confusing.